# Execution plan showing high hash match

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index-tuning, view, hashing

i have a sql query running from database 1 that joins table **company** on to a view

```
SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM([K].[cmpCompanyCode]) AS [cmpCompanyCode]
FROM [dbo].[view] AS [K]  

JOIN [database2].[dbo].[Company] AS [C]  
ON [K].[cmpCompanyCode] = [C].[CmpCompanyCode];
```

this is my view

```
SELECT RTRIM([CM].[fkOrganizationIDParent]) AS [fkOrganizationIDParent],
          [C].[cmpCoID],
          RTRIM([CE].[ClientNumber]) AS [cmpCompanyCode],

          ISNULL([CE].[z_DoNotReplicate], 0) AS [DoNotReplicateSupervisors],
          ISNULL([CE].[z_StopPTOReplication], 0) AS [StopPtoReplication]        
    FROM   [dbo].[Client] AS [CM] WITH(NOLOCK)
          JOIN [dbo].[Entity] AS [CE] WITH(NOLOCK) ON [CM].[fkProjectID] = [CE].[fkProjectID]
          JOIN [database2].[dbo].[Company] AS [C] ON [CE].[ClientNumber] = [C].[CmpCompanyCode]
    WHERE  [CM].[z_K] = 1
          AND ISNULL([CE].[z_Exclude], 0) = 0   
          AND [CM].[crStatus] <> 'Terminated'
          AND [CM].[IsActive] = 1
          AND [CE].[IsActive] = 1
          AND ISNULL(RTRIM([CE].[ClientNumber]), '') <> '';
```

but when i run the first query my execution plan shows me a high hash.

Output List says **dbo.company.CmpCoid, expr1016**
[image: hash]

i have indexes on the dbo.company table as follows

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_CompanyCode] ON [dbo].[Company]
(
    [CmpCompanyCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CDX_CompanyName] ON [dbo].[Company]
(
    [CmpCompanyName] ASC,
    [CmpCoID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

im not sure how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see a problem. Are you referring to the `Cost %` metric?...That's just an estimate (so it's not very useful to look at) and every execution plan's costs have to add up to 100% (sans rounding errors), so your plan will always have costs distributed throughout it like such. Provide the **actual** execution plan via [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) which tells us how long in execution time each operator ran for (generally).

Comment: i thought if i improved the efficiency of the join the cost metric would be cheaper?

Comment: You may reduce the cost without having any impact on the runtime whatsoever. Is this query actually slow?

Comment: @deanpillow The cost has to go somewhere, it's relative to the entire plan, it'll always add up (roughly) to 100%. That's not actually indicating a problem (or that there's anything to improve) by itself though. To re-emphasize what Erik said, is this query actually slow running and if so, what operator in the **actual** execution plan has the longest runtime?